# Looking to ID a short Sci-Fi Story about a science team eating plants on alien planet

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A science team accidentally lands on a new planet that is covered with plants.  Possibly marooned there? They eventually start to eat the plants and the side effect is that they begin to lose their intelligence.  This is told in the form of dairy entries by the captain of the group. He eventually succumbs after eating the plants; his last journal entry is made up of non-sense characters like curliques, etc.

1960s-1980s?